# How do I release a Crystal Report object when an asp.net page closes

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have a asp .net 3.5 app using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

I have an issue with a report preview screen.

If I don't dispose of the report object in the page unload the object stays active and never goes away until the application pool of the site is recycled. Also, the temp files created by the report are not cleaned up at that point.

If I dispose of the report object in the form unload, the object is released and the temp files are removed.

But if I do that, then the report object is gone and if the user selects the option to export the report (from the viewer control on the page that is still open) I get the error:

```
not set to an instance of on object
```

In my ReportViewer page I just have the viewer control.

In the page load I create the report object and pass it to the viewer. This all works great.

My disposal code is the a method that handles `MyBase.Unload`, right now my problem is that this event is fired even when the page isn't being closed and I cant find an event that would be like the closing event on a normal window.

**What do i need to do to properly dispose of the report object, but not until after the viewer is actually closed?**

Comment: thanks for the edit dcaswell, that makes it look much better

Answer (score 1):

```
      private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose(); //context means your crystal report document object.
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to this issue that works properly.

This can only be accomplished by using a script and a little extra code

in the report viewer's .aspx file i had to add a script and an onunload call

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function cleanupCR() {
        __doPostBack('', 'DisposeOfCR');
        }
</script>
```

and

```
<body onunload="cleanupCR()">
```

then in the report viewers .aspx.vb file i modified my post back catch to handel the disposing of the crystal reports objects

```
If Me.IsPostBack Then
    rpt = Session(Me.HIDDENRPTKEY.Value)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    If (Me.Request.Params("__EVENTARGUMENT") = "DisposeOfCR") Then
        DisposeOfReportObject()
    End If
    Return
End If
```

and finally in the same i added the method to dispose of the report objects:

```
If rpt IsNot Nothing Then
    Try
        If rpt.Database IsNot Nothing Then
            rpt.Database.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    rpt.Close()
    rpt.Dispose()
End If
```

if the report database object is invalid the rpt.Database test will throw an error and for now i just put the empty catch there to allow for that. i will have to find the proper way to test that value so it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not writing the

```
Report.Close();
Report.Dispose();
```

in the Page_Unload?

This will clear them as well, and you can use them till the time they are (Export them etc).
Its working at my end.